# How to set value in array form with Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to set value in array like this:

```js
this.form.controls[name].setValue('name')
```

but I am working with array forms, and this is not working, even if I pass an array index explicitly

for example, this is my form array and I want to do is to set value in a function

```js
user: FormGroup;
users: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.user = this.buildGroup();
  this.users = this.fb.group({
    data: this.fb.array([this.user])
  });
}
get fData() {
  return this.users.get('data') as FormArray;
}
buildGroup() {
  return this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    account: this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      confirm: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  });
}
setValue(index) {
  // This doesn't work
  this.fData[index].controls[name].setValue('name')
}
onSubmit() {
  this.fData.push(this.buildGroup());
  const {valid, value} = this.fData;
  console.log(valid, value);
}
```

Comment: Scrap my previous answer. The problem is most likely that you are not [passing an array to setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#example-1).

Comment: Should not to pass the index, to the specific array form? I am tryng this but this is not working                                                                 setValue(index) {
   this.fData.setValue(['Name']);
} The error says that must supply a value for fom control with name 'name'

Comment: Try this: `this.fData[index].controls['name'].setValue(['name'])`

Comment: not working: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Answer (score 34):

For arrays, you need to use `setControl`. Something like this:

```
    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
        productName: ['', [Validators.required,
                           Validators.minLength(3),
                           Validators.maxLength(50)]],
        productCode: ['', Validators.required],
        starRating: ['', NumberValidators.range(1, 5)],
        tags: this.fb.array([]),
        description: ''
    });

    ...

    // Update the data on the form
    this.productForm.patchValue({
        productName: this.product.productName,
        productCode: this.product.productCode,
        starRating: this.product.starRating,
        description: this.product.description
    });
    this.productForm.setControl('tags', this.fb.array(this.product.tags || []));
```

Comment: I must have missed that in your pluralsight course ;-)

Comment: Found it: https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=angular-2-reactive-forms&author=deborah-kurata&name=angular-2-reactive-forms-m8&clip=5&mode=live&start=348.941

Comment: The "Angular: Reactive Forms" course? Hope it was helpful!

Comment: LOL! Wish we could add emojis to comments!

Comment: How can I loop through this array in the html?

Comment: it's also right here

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

just search "setControl"

Comment: @DeborahK How can we add few formGroups to formArray like this?
If our `template` has `[formGroupName]="index"` other than `[formControlName]="index"` this approach gives this error "ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'addresses -> 0 -> addressType'". any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I was using control.push() but control.setControl() was exactly what I needed!!

Comment: Thank you!!! But, I'm literally starting to hate Angular...

Comment: Why is that? Is it just the forms part?

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I have done to set value manually in `formArray`'s specific form control and worked for me. I have `formArray` named as `bundleDetails`.

```js
this.formBuilderObj['bundleDetails'] = 
this.formBuilder.array([this.createBundleItem()]);
   
createBundleItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        bsku: ['', Validators.required],
        bqty: ['', Validators.required],
        bprice: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

Method to set bsku control's value (where index is `[formGroupName]="i"` passed from an HTML file).

```js
setSku(sku: string, index: number) {
   const faControl = 
   (<FormArray>this.pmForm.controls['bundleDetails']).at(index);
   faControl['controls'].bsku.setValue(sku);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the error "ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'addresses -> 0 -> addressType'" or something similar, it's most likely cause you're passing the values in but your html template is expecting values along with a control name.

To resolve this, iterate over each item in your array, and create a new form group instance for each value - based on what your view is expecting - then push to a new array variable, which we then set in our form.

See code below:

```
var tagsArray = [];
this.product.tags.forEach(product => tagsArray.push(this.fb.group({tag: [product.tag, [Validators.required]]})));
this.productForm.setControl('tags', this.fb.array(tagsArray || []));
```

Referenced in view like so:

```
<div class="tag" *ngFor="let t of tags.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i" class="mb-2">
      <input type="text" formControlName="tag" placeholder="Tag name" class="primary_input">
       <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteTag(i)">
           <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
       </button>
 </div>
```

This lets you load previous results while enabling the ability to add more values and validate user input.

Hope this helps.