# Angular2: Cannot find form control at index 1 at FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, formarray

During runtime I am getting all records from the JSON object and in form-control I am getting the values. However, in form-array I am getting only the first of many records.

The error shown in the console:

> Cannot find form control at index 1 at FormArray._throwIfControlMissing

Image of JSON object and error:

[image]

1. Interface

```js
export interface IService {
    ServiceID: number,
    Name: string,
    Staffs: IStaffView[]
}

export interface IStaffView {
    StaffServiceID: number,
    StaffID: number,
    Name: string
}
```

2. Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray , Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { RESTService } from '../../Service/REST.service';
import { IService, IStaffView } from '../../Model/service.model';
import { DBOperation } from '../../Shared/enum';
import { Global } from '../../Shared/global';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-service-detail',
    templateUrl: 'app/Components/service-detail/service-detail.component.html'
})

export class ServiceDetailComponent implements OnInit {
   
    service: IService;
    services: IService[];
    staffview: IStaffView;
    staffsview: IStaffView[];

    serviceFrm: FormGroup;
    Staffs: FormArray;

    msg: string;
    indLoading: boolean = false;
    btnTitle: string;
    dbops: DBOperation;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private _restService: RESTService,
        private location: Location,
        private _route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {
        const id = this._route.snapshot.params['id'];
        if (!id || id == 0) {
            this.btnTitle = 'Save';
            this.dbops = DBOperation.create;
        } else {
            this.btnTitle = 'Edit';
            this.dbops = DBOperation.update
        }
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        //this.Staffs = this.fb.array([
        //    this.initStaff()
        //]);


        this.serviceFrm = this.fb.group({
            ServiceID: [''],
            Name: ['', Validators.required],
            Staffs: this.fb.array([
                this.initStaff()
            ])
        });

        this.getService();
    }

    initStaff() {
        return this.fb.group({
            StaffServiceID: [''],
            StaffID: [''],
            Name: ['']
        });
    }

    getService(): void {
        const id = parseInt(this._route.snapshot.params['id']);
        if (id && id > 0) {
            this.indLoading = true;
            this._restService.getById('/api/serviceapi/', id)
                .subscribe(resp => this.serviceFrm.setValue(resp)
                , error => this.msg = <any>error);
        }
    }

}
```

3. HTML Code

```html
  <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Staffs</label>
                    </div>
                    <div formArrayName="Staffs">
                        <div *ngFor="let staff of serviceFrm.controls.Staffs.controls; let i=index" formGroupName="{{i}}">
                            <div>
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The mentioned error is caused by calling `this.serviceFrm.setValue(resp)` (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1382).

> This method performs strict checks, so it will throw an error if you try
> to set the value of a control that doesn't exist or if you exclude the
> value of a control.

You are trying to assign an array of 3 items (according to your snapshot) to FormArray having only one initial FormGroup at index 0, so assigning value at index 1 fails, as it does not exist.

To solve it empty your form array before patching value, use `patchValue()` (which accepts partial value) instead of `setValue()` and then push each value in a loop:

```
getService(): void {
  const id = parseInt(this._route.snapshot.params['id']);
  if (id && id > 0) {
    this.indLoading = true;
    this._restService.getById('/api/serviceapi/', id).subscribe(
      resp => {
        // get form array reference
        const staffs = this.serviceFrm.get('Staffs') as FormArray;
        // empty form array
        while (staffs.length) {
          staffs.removeAt(0);
        }
        // use patchValue instead of setValue
        this.serviceFrm.patchValue(resp);
        // add form array values in a loop
        resp.Staffs.forEach(staff => staffs.push(this.fb.group(staff));
      }, 
      error => this.msg = <any>error
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Andriy, patchValue is working. and while loop also working thank a lot

Comment: you are right (about removing items), I updated my answer with while loop removing all previous values

Comment: You sir had save my day!

Comment: tried this and it seems to work but for some reason valueChanges no longer emits a value

Comment: @Roj, please note that this was answere 1.5 years ago, for  different Angular version. If you want please create a stackblitz example with your issue and I will try to help. Or post a new question mentioning Angular version

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use `setControl` with FormArrays. The code below is an example from [Deborah Kurata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987480/how-to-set-value-in-array-form-with-angular):

```
this.productForm = this.fb.group({
productName: ['', [Validators.required,
                       Validators.minLength(3),
                       Validators.maxLength(50)]],
productCode: ['', Validators.required],
starRating: ['', NumberValidators.range(1, 5)],
tags: this.fb.array([]),
description: ''
});

...

// Update the data on the form
this.productForm.patchValue({
    productName: this.product.productName,
    productCode: this.product.productCode,
    starRating: this.product.starRating,
    description: this.product.description
});

// This line makes the array update!
this.productForm.setControl('tags', this.fb.array(this.product.tags || []));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Staffs</label>
                     </div>
                    <div >
                        <div *ngFor="let staff of serviceFrm.controls.Staffs.controls; let i=index" formArrayName="Staffs">
                            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, but unfortunately this code is not working for me, giving this -- Error: Cannot find control with name: '0'